# JTextPane is not increasing its height and cutting HTML content

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I'm building a Swing GUi application and need to display simple HTML in text fragments (text messages with formatting and lists, maybe tables, and images). So I chose to use JTextPane which can render HTML.

I have the following element structure in my GUI:

jSplitPane -> jScrollPane -> jPanel ->
jPanel with GroupLayout (Message element) ->
jPanel wrapper for message content (HTML content jTextPane plus audio player custom jPanels)->
jTextPane with HTML message content

The problem is that jTextPane is cutting its content, even though none of its parents is limiting its maximum height.

I don't know, why it is happening.

Here is the MessageView structure:

[image: MessageView jPanel structure]

General GUI structure:

[image: General GUI structure]

Here is the result when the program is running:

[image: Result]

Here is the HTML of the text message:

```
<div style="padding: 0px 3px; font-size: 14px; font-family: Tahoma">
    Some <i>text</i><br>And more,<br>And more...<br>And more...<br>And more...<br>
    And more...<br>And more...<br>
    <img src="http://popov654.pp.ru/copybox/photo.jpg" width="390" height=\"260\">";
</div>
```

Also after setting jTextPane HTML content I use this code (found it on the net):

```
try {
    Dimension d = msgContent.getPreferredSize();
    Rectangle r = msgContent.modelToView(msgContent.getDocument().getLength());
    d.height = r.y + r.height;
    msgContent.setPreferredSize(d);
    JFrame topFrame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
    topFrame.getContentPane().validate();
} catch (Exception ex) {}
```

Without this code the jTextPane was just 30-40 pixels in height. But what is the most interesting, when I change the line 4 where d.height is set, and add 100 or 200 more to it, nothing is changed at all on the display.

UPDATE: commented out this block of code, and it did not change anything too at this moment.

What am I missing? Any ideas?

Comment: In the `editor` JPanel, is the JTextPane within a JScrollPane?

Comment: `editor` is the lower block with the textarea, I think it has nothing to do with the issue

Comment: I think the `JTextPane` should be wrapped in a `JScrollPane`.  The "problem" is, setting the text of the `JTextPane` won't cause a layout of the html to occur immediately, and you generally won't know when it's actually complete up-to-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems  I found a working solution (though I'm not sure it is the best one).

I added the following code after setting HTML content:

```
msgContent.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(msgContent.getWidth(), msgContent.getPreferredSize().height + 20));

setPreferredSize(new Dimension(getWidth(), msgContent.getPreferredSize().height + 160));
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(msgContent.getHeight() + ", " + getHeight());
    }
});
```

It is looking good now, I have the proper message height and working vertical scrolling in `msgsList` container.